# How can I make time measurement DRY in my bash scripts?

Tags: bash, function, time

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314370/168855) answer, to measure the time in my bash scripts I can use:

```
start_time="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
sleep 5
end_time="$(date -u +%s.%N)"

elapsed="$(bc <<<"$end_time-$start_time")"
echo "Total of $elapsed seconds elapsed for process"
```

And it works great. However, since  I have a lot of script files, I would love to simplify and DRY code. For example I want to achieve this code:

```
. /time.sh

start_time=now
sleep 5
end_time=now

measure_time
```

In other words, I want to have another script named `time.sh` that can be included anywhere and it should have two functions. One to replace `"$(date -u +%s.%N)"` part, and one to replace `"$(bc <<<"$end_time-$start_time")"` part.

I tried to create these functions, but then I realized that in the shell, we couldn't return values from functions. We can only return numbers.

Is there a way to simplify the code above, to the code below?

Comment: You can "return" values in a function by using echo and assign the output of that function to a variable. For example if you have:
`hello() { sleep 1; echo hi; }`
And you use:
`value=$(hello) ; echo $value`
The output will be `hi`

Comment: Or you can try passing a function as parameter to another function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672289/bash-pass-a-function-as-parameter

Comment: In bash, you can get the elapsed time more directly by manipulating the builtin `SECONDS` variable - see for example [Time elapsed of a bash script (days/minutes/seconds)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589072/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver but not the nanoseconds the OP seems to want

Comment: Have you thought about using `time` inside a script (also on a function)? See `type time`, `help time` and `man time`.   General use `time MyExecutableScript.sh` or `time /bin/bash MyScript.sh`. In your script can be something like `MyFunction(){....}` then `time MyFunction` or `A="$((time MyFunction) 2>&1)"`. Note that you need a subshell `(...)` to redirect the output of time.

Comment: One huge simplification would be to use seconds without nanoseconds.  Collect the seconds-since-the epoch timestamp with `date -u +%s` just before the start and just after the end of a command, and the shell can do the integer subtraction to give you the elapsed time.  No need to call `bc` to do floating point operations.  But if sub-second precision is what you need, it's what you need.

Comment: @SottoVoce Another huge simplification would be to use the shell `SECONDS` variable. No external executable to call, less cpu time wasted.

Answer (score 5):

In latest versions of bash (5.0+), there is a variable that give the time with precision of microseconds (6 fractional digits). If that is enough precision for your uses, you may try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash --
time_diff(){ 
    local elapsed="$(bc <<<"${send}-${start}")"
    echo "Total of $elapsed seconds elapsed for process";
 }

start=$EPOCHREALTIME
sleep 5
end=$EPOCHREALTIME

time_diff
```

This script is faster to get time values than calling an external executable (`date`) to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

What is wrong with `time ./script.sh` ?

Simple example:-

time sleep 5

```
real    0m5.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form, this sounds like what you're after.

```
now(){
  date -u +%s.%N
}

measure_time(){
  local elapsed="$(bc <<<"$end_time-$start_time")"
  echo "Total of $elapsed seconds elapsed for process"
}

start_time="$(now)"
sleep 5
end_time="$(now)"

measure_time
```

You could make the `now` function accept a named variable and adapt the `measure_time` function to handle that, but it would be an unnecessary complication if your use case is to track one process at a time.

Having said that, here's an iteration in that direction.  `start` and `end` are arbitrary labels, so you could call them what ever suits, if you were tracking multiple events.

```
stamp(){
  time[$1]="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
}

measure_time(){
  local elapsed="$(bc <<<"${time[$2]}-${time[$1]}")"
  echo "Total of $elapsed seconds elapsed for process"
}

declare -A time=()

stamp start
sleep 5
stamp end

measure_time start end
```

EDIT:

### Caveat

As the figures in roaima's answer show, this is not going to be high precision, because each action (particularly so sub shells and external processes) will pad the reported time out by some fraction of a second. This probably doesn't matter for multi-minute processes (in which case why measure nano seconds?) but will become more pronounced at lower run times, to the point of being almost meaningless. Though the problem was rather less severe in my tests as compared to roaima's.  It rather depends on what you are using that data for.

ANOTHER EDIT:

Responding to QuartzCrystal's fair comment, herein lies a further iteration which, it turns out, is converging on roaima's answer -- probably indicating they are on the "best" track.

```
_stamp(){
  time[${1:?}]="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
}

_start() {
  _stamp "start${1:+_${1}}"
}

_end() {
  _stamp "end${1:+_${1}}"
}

measure_time(){
  local elapsed="$(bc <<<"${time[end${1:+_${1}}]}-${time[start${1:+_${1}}]}")"
  echo "Total of $elapsed seconds elapsed${1:+ for process ${1}}"
}

declare -A time=()

_start
sleep 5
_end

measure_time

_start foo
sleep 1
_start bar
sleep 2
_end foo
_end bar

measure_time foo
measure_time bar
```

Comment: Inside the functions, what if `$1` or `$2` are empty or unset? Hint: use `${1:-_default}` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that requires associative arrays (`bash`, etc.)

To be placed in an example `timers.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
########################################################################
declare -A _timers

# Declare and start a timer. Optional name
startTimer() {
    _timers[${1:-_}_s]=$(date -u +'%s.%N')
}

# End a timer. Optional name
endTimer() {
    _timers[${1:-_}_e]=$(date -u +'%s.%N')
}

# Report on the duration of a timer. Optional name
diffTimer() {
    local s=${_timers[${1:-_}_s]} e=${_timers[${1:-_}_e]}
    bc <<< "${e:-$(date -u +'%s.%N')} - ${s:-0}"
}
```

Main code

```
#!/bin/bash
. timers.sh

startTimer
sleep 2
startTimer sub
sleep 0.1
endTimer sub
endTimer

echo "Elapsed $(diffTimer) and for sub $(diffTimer sub)"
```

Output

```
Elapsed 2.321831200 and for sub .183521000
```

Without a parameter the functions act on a default timer. Otherwise they act on the named timer. If you don't call `startTimer` or `endTimer` the default values of `0` and *now* are used. Timers are stored in the global associative array `_timers[]`